# After integrating jenkins with ansible and then build the job,it is throwing the error sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory

Tags: sshpass

After integrating ansible with jenkins, then after invoke ansible playbook, i gave some credentials and built the job, 
after this step "[devops-cicd] $ sshpass ******** /bin/ansible-playbook /var/lib/jenkins/worksapce/devops-cicd/myapp.yml -i /etc/ansible/hosts -u sudheeransi -k
then it is throwing the error sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when path to ansible binaries directory was set up incorrectly in Jenkins. Also check if sshpass itself is installed on your system.